# Web Part Properties in different pages

Tags: web-part, custom, properties

Soo,

I created an webpart, and I've added a custom property.
The webpart works fine.

Now I want to add this webpart in another page also, but with a different property value.
The problem is that if I set the property value it will update all the values in all the webparts of this type in my site.

What should I do?

Here is my code:

```
[ToolboxItemAttribute(false)]
public class ListWebPart : WebPart
{
    public static string List;
    [Category("Extended Settings"),
    Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.Shared),
    WebBrowsable(true),
    WebDisplayName("List"),
    WebDescription("Please Enter a Sample List"),
    DefaultValue("Posts")]

    ect
```

PS: Shorty scenario
If you add a web part in page 1 and set the title: Webpartbla
than you add the same web part in another page and set the title: webpartbla1 
it will remember this values of the same webpart in different pages.
This won't work with custom properties, like the one above

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't make property List static

EDIT:

Working code:

```
[ToolboxItemAttribute(false)]
public class MyDetailWebPart : WebPart {
  ...
  [Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.Shared)]
  [WebBrowsable(true)]
  [Category("Category")]
  [WebDisplayName("Name")]
  [Description("Desc")]
  public string Code { get; set; }
  ...
  protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        var control = (MyControl)Page.LoadControl(_ascxPath);
        control.Code = Code;
        Controls.Add(control);
    }
}

public partial class MyControl : UserControl
{
  ...
  public string Code { get; set; }
  ...
}
```